# How to dynamically call accessor methods in my model object from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model:

```
class Mymodel < ActiveRecord :: Base

  attr_accessible :the_date, :the_time, :the_event

  def the_date
    ...
  end

  def the_time
    ...
  end

  def the_event
    ...
  end
...
end
```

My controller holds a array of methods names, which is used by view:

```
class Mycontroller < ApplicationController

  @methods=['the_date', 'the_time', 'the_event']
  ...
end
```

in my view ***index.html.haml***, I would like to dynamically access the model methods:

```
%td
  -index=SOME_USER_INPUT
  =mymodel.@methods[index] /IT DOES NOT WORK HERE!!
```

But, I can not dynamically call the model methods in this way: `mymodel.@methods[index]`, how to have dynamical method call based on my sample code??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call methods dynamically based on their name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349624/how-to-call-methods-dynamically-based-on-their-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@methods` is an instance variable of your controller, not of your model. Assuming you want to call the method, try this:

`=mymodel.send(@methods[index])`