# How to call methods dynamically based on their name?

Tags: ruby, dynamic, metaprogramming

How can I call a method dynamically when its name is contained in a string variable? For example:

```
class MyClass
  def foo; end
  def bar; end
end

obj = MyClass.new
str = get_data_from_user  # e.g. `gets`, `params`, DB access, etc.
str  #=> "foo"
# somehow call `foo` on `obj` using the value in `str`.
```

How can I do this? Is doing so a security risk?

Comment: This sounds like a code smell. It sounds like those methods could be refactored so you don't have to go down this confusing path

Comment: For dynamic params you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21441197/1770571

Comment: You can use send() or public_send(), send() only use for private or protected method

Answer (score 155, accepted):

What you want to do is called [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch). It’s very easy in Ruby, just use [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send):

```
method_name = 'foobar'
obj.public_send(method_name) if obj.respond_to? method_name
```

If the method is private/protected, use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) instead, but prefer `public_send`.

This is a potential security risk if the value of `method_name` comes from the user. To prevent vulnerabilities, you should validate which methods can be actually called. For example:

```
if obj.respond_to?(method_name) && %w[foo bar].include?(method_name)
  obj.send(method_name)
end
```

Answer (score 115):

There are multiple ways to accomplish dynamic dispatch in Ruby, each with their own advantages and disadvantages. Care should be taken to select the most appropriate method for the situation.

The following table breaks down some of the more common techniques:

```
+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
|    Method     | Arbitrary Code? | Access Private? | Dangerous? | Fastest On |
+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
| eval          | Yes             | No              | Yes        | TBD        |
| instance_eval | Yes             | No              | Yes        | TBD        |
| send          | No              | Yes             | Yes        | TBD        |
| public_send   | No              | No              | Yes        | TBD        |
| method        | No              | Yes             | Yes        | TBD        |
+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
```

### Arbitrary Code

Some techniques are limited to calling methods only, while others can execute basically anything. Methods that allow execution of arbitrary code should be [used with extreme caution, if not avoided altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/q/637421/525478).

### Access Private

Some techniques are limited to calling public methods only, while others can call both public and private methods. Ideally, you should strive to use the method with the least amount of visibility that fulfills your requirements.

***Note***: If a technique can execute arbitrary code, it can easily be used to access private methods that it might not otherwise have access to.

### Dangerous

Just because a technique can not execute arbitrary code or call a private method does not mean that it is safe, particularly if you are using user-provided values. Delete is a public method.

### Fastest on

Some of these techniques may be more performant than others, depending on your Ruby version. Benchmarks to follow....

---

## Examples

```
class MyClass
  def foo(*args); end

  private

  def bar(*args); end
end

obj = MyClass.new
```

### eval

```
eval('obj.foo') #=> nil
eval('obj.bar') #=> NoMethodError: private method `bar' called

# With arguments:
eval('obj.foo(:arg1, :arg2)') #=> nil
eval('obj.bar(:arg1, :arg2)') #=> NoMethodError: private method `bar' called
```

### instance_eval

```
obj.instance_eval('foo') #=> nil 
obj.instance_eval('bar') #=> nil 

# With arguments:
obj.instance_eval('foo(:arg1, :arg2)') #=> nil 
obj.instance_eval('bar(:arg1, :arg2)') #=> nil
```

### send

```
obj.send('foo') #=> nil 
obj.send('bar') #=> nil 

# With arguments:
obj.send('foo', :arg1, :arg2) #=> nil 
obj.send('bar', :arg1, :arg2) #=> nil
```

### public_send

```
obj.public_send('foo') #=> nil 
obj.public_send('bar') #=> NoMethodError: private method `bar' called

# With arguments:
obj.public_send('foo', :arg1, :arg2) #=> nil 
obj.public_send('bar', :arg1, :arg2) #=> NoMethodError: private method `bar' called
```

### method

```
obj.method('foo').call #=> nil 
obj.method('bar').call #=> nil

# With arguments:
obj.method('foo').call(:arg1, :arg2) #=> nil 
obj.method('bar').call(:arg1, :arg2) #=> nil
```

Comment: I have a good bit of interest in this answer. I don't care a huge amount about the benchmarks, but I do want to know if you can assume from the above description that `public_send` is the least dangerous of these possibilities.

Comment: @MattSchuchard You could probably make that argument, but it is still not really safe if the method is coming from unvalidated user input. If it is coming from user input it really should be checked against a whitelist of allowed methods, unless you are ok with a user supplying "delete_all" or something similar...

Comment: It is especially worth noting that, if the user is supplying both the method names and the arguments, then `public_send` can be used to call `send`, which can in turn be used to call `eval`, or `system`: `obj.public_send('send','system','rm','-r','-f','/')` will ruin your day.

Comment: Great explanations, thank you @BradWerth

Answer (score 14):

You are **really** going to want to be careful with this.  Using user data to call any method via `send` could leave room open for users to execute any method they want.  `send` is often used to call method names dynamically—but make sure the input values are *trusted* and can't be manipulated by users.

Golden rule is never trust any input that comes from the user.

Comment: "Golden rule is never trust any input that comes from the user." taking notes!

Answer (score 12):

Use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) to call a method dynamically:

```
obj.send(str)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can check the method availability using `respond_to?`. If it's available then you call `send`. For example:

```
if obj.respond_to?(str)
  obj.send(str)
end
```