# Ruby: Creating a hash key and value from a variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, syntax

I have a variable `id` and I want to use it as a key in a hash so that the value assigned to the variable is used as key of the hash.

For instance, if I have the variable `id = 1` the desired resulting hash would be `{ 1: 'foo' }`.

I've tried creating the hash with,

```
{
  id: 'foo'
}
```

But that doesn't work, instead resulting in a hash with the symbol `:id` to `'foo'`.

I could have sworn I've done this before but I am completely drawing a blank.

Comment: `h = {}; h[id] = 'foo'` or `Hash[id, 'foo']`

Comment: @Gumbo, can you make your comment into an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @muistooshort, that is accessing, not creation, it's a different operation. Also Gumbo's comment show that the syntax is different.

Comment: I've tried to clean up the question. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I'm having a tough time parsing what the posted answer is getting at but a good FYI is that you can't use the Ruby 1.9 style of `{ id: 'foo' }` if `id` is a variable. You need to use `{ id => 'foo' }` for it to interpolate the value of `id`.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

If you want to populate a new hash with certain values, you can pass them to [`Hash::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
Hash["a", 100, "b", 200]             #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
Hash[ [ ["a", 100], ["b", 200] ] ]   #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
Hash["a" => 100, "b" => 200]         #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
```

So in your case:

```
Hash[id, 'foo']
Hash[[[id, 'foo']]]
Hash[id => 'foo']
```

The last syntax `id => 'foo'` can also be used with `{}`:

```
{ id => 'foo' }
```

Otherwise, if the hash already exists, use [`Hash#=[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D):

```
h = {}
h[id] = 'foo'
```

Comment: I was confused with question itself, now this answer made me double confused. :( Could you tell me what was OP asking?

Comment: @ArupRakshit OP wants to use the value of `id` as key. `{ id: 'foo' }` doesn’t work as `id: 'foo'` is equivalent to `:id => 'foo'`.

Comment: Ah so the old style hash syntax works, but not the new style. Thank you.

Comment: @James: The JavaScript style only works with a [limited set of symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8675314/479863) and only works in Hash literals. You can't use the JavaScript style if the key not a symbol (with a limited format).

Comment: What's really cool is _mixing_ the styles: `x = :a; puts ({y: 3, x => 5})`

Comment: in `Ecmascript 6` you can build hashes using `variables` like `a = {"a": 100}` and `b = {"b": 200}` then `{a, b}` will be `=> {"a": 100, "b": 200}` but I don't believe this feauture exist in ruby

Comment: Also, If you want to use a **key** and **value** that are variables you can use: `MyHash = {  id => foo, id2 => foo2 }` OR `MyHash = Hash[id, foo, id2, foo2]`. If only the **key** is a variable then use: `MyHash = {  id => 'foo', id2 => 'foo2' }` OR `MyHash = Hash[id, 'foo', id2, 'foo2']`

Comment: You can also write it with string interpolation: `h = { "#{id}" => 'foo' }`