# Update params with passed value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to create a generic method to update certain params of my model.

Example:

```
@parameter = "name"

User.update(@parameter: "new name here")
```

So here I would like to update the column "name" with the value "new name here". But this method isn't working. Any Idea of how I should do it?

Comment: You tagged your question with [ruby-on-rails]. Are you trying to do this in a Ruby on Rails model class?

Comment: No just into my controller to access to external values like params[:something]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Can you update your question with what you are actually trying to do? I think we're facing a case of [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the `{ x: foo }` hash syntax when the keys are literals in the source code (like `:x` in that example). If you want to use the value of a variable as the key to a hash you have to use the old style hashrocket syntax like this:

```
  User.update(@parameter => "new name here")
```

(That's not strictly the only way to do it, see this answer for more: [Creating a hash key from a variable in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440745/creating-a-hash-key-from-a-variable-in-ruby))

Comment: @Archer do you mean "#{@parameter}" ?

Comment: Due to typo... This version is also possible: User.update("#{@parameter}": "new name here")