# How to dynamic update columns in Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic

I have an array of the desired columns to edit (wich is dynamic), like this:

```
toEdit = ["last_name_required", "email_required", "phone_required"]
```

Remember, it is dynamic so it can have only the phone. For example:

```
toEdit = ["phone_required"]
```

I have a Model with SQL Columns like:

```
last_name_required
email_required
phone_required
```

Those columns accept boolean values.

I want to generate a code to edit columns with the array values as parameters. Like this:

```
o = Model.fist
o.last_name_required = true
o.phone_required = true
o.save
```

I've tried something like:

```
o = Model.first
o.toEdit[0] = true
o.toEdit[1] = true
o.save
```

But I understand is wrong because I am trying to use a string as an object.

I don't know what's the appropriate syntax.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
o = Model.new
toEdit.each do |key|
  o.send "#{key}=".to_sym, true
end
o.save
```

Comment: Brilliant. It's working. May I know why did you use the commas and then the .to_sym function?

Comment: Be careful with this if `key` is from user input... http://stackoverflow.com/a/26284769/525478

Comment: @EmmanuelOrozco Sure; the comma since the call is actually `o.send("#{key.to_sym}=", true)`, so the first parameter is the symbol name of the function, and the second parameter is the value, in this case, `true`.  Regarding, to_sym, it's just what's used by the method signature.  Details: http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send

Comment: @EmmanuelOrozco Actually thanks for pointing that out I noticed I left my answer a bit superfluous.  You can use EITHER to_sym or string, but certainly both are not required (although, as you see, it works).  The updated answer can be used either with or without the to_sym.  I always use to_sym just because I always have (and the docs say so), but it doesn't seem to be required.  Also, I would emphasize what @Brad said, make sure you control what goes in that array, otherwise something like `['phone_required', 'destroy']` could be harmful

Comment: to_sym is not really needed here

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code.

```
toEdit = ["last_name_required", "email_required", "phone_required"]
object = Model.new
object.columns.map(&:name).each do |column_name|
    object.column_name = true if  (toEdit.includes? column_name)
end
```

Comment: I highly doubt that object.column_name is going to work, it should throw NoMethodError: undefined method `column_name='