# Rails - How to use variable as part of method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add variable name into method_name in rails. I am getting error.

```
**Controller ACTION**
=====================
def my_action(state)
   method_#{state}
end

**Model methods**
====================
def method_start
end

def method_end
end
```

how to call method with variable name i am not getting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call methods dynamically based on their name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349624/how-to-call-methods-dynamically-based-on-their-name)

Comment: here i need to call different model methods. is it possible using this method?

Comment: Class_eval is typical pattern for meta-programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object.send` to call method by name. For example,

```
def my_action(state)
  if [:start, :end].include?(state)
    model.send("method_#{state}")
  end
end
```

**Make sure to validate `state` variable for security.** `Object.send` can call any method including private ones.

Comment: Whenever possible, it's better to use `public_send` when calling from outside the class. `public_send` can only call public methods, not private ones. Calling a private method from outside the containing class breaks encapsulation and should be avoided.