# Setting if conditions to self.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-oauth, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I'm working with Twitter and Facebook omni auth

I've this method that creates a user

```
    def self.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
        user = where(provider: auth_hash[:provider], uid: auth_hash[:uid]).first_or_create
        user.update(
            name: auth_hash.info.name,
            profile_image: auth_hash.info.image,
            token: auth_hash.credentials.token,
            secret: auth_hash.credentials.secret,
            url: auth_hash.info.urls.Twitter,
            nickname: auth_hash.info.nickname
            )
        user
    end
```

How do I make it so that if provider is Twitter do

```
url: auth_hash.info.urls.Twitter,
```

But if provider is Facebook, do this instead

```
url: auth_hash.info.urls.Facebook,
```

Comment: The answers here may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349624/how-to-call-methods-dynamically-based-on-their-name

Answer (score 0):

you can change the code like :
`url: auth_hash.info.urls.auth_hash[:provider]`

`auth_hash[:provider]` either return Facebook OR Twitter