# Using Enumerables across multiple objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm playing around with Ruby [on Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/ruby-beginner-en-L3ZCI/1/3?curriculum_id=5059f8619189a5000201fbcb) and not sure how to reduce this further. Current code is:

```
group_1 = [4.1, 5.5, 3.2, 3.3, 6.1, 3.9, 4.7]
group_2 = [7.0, 3.8, 6.2, 6.1, 4.4, 4.9, 3.0]
group_3 = [5.5, 5.1, 3.9, 4.3, 4.9, 3.2, 3.2]

over_4_feet = Proc.new { |height| height >= 4 }

can_ride_1 = group_1.select(&over_4_feet)
can_ride_2 = group_2.select(&over_4_feet)
can_ride_3 = group_3.select(&over_4_feet)
```

I wonder how I could get to something like this:

```
can_ride_(1..3).each {|x| group_(x).select(&over_4_feet)}
```

Is it possible, when objects hold repeatable patterns like these do, to use an Enumerable method in this way? I don't mind if it's a regex, but curious about what pattern might be recommended.

Comment: have you looked at .send http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349624/how-to-call-methods-dynamically-based-on-their-name

Comment: I think dynamic dispatch is what you are looking for ...

Comment: @mahatmanich doesn't `group_#{x}` work ? I remember seeing this `#` somewhere

Comment: Actually `.call` `.send` `.eval` are doing similar things => http://blog.khd.me/ruby/ruby-dynamic-method-calling/

Comment: @niceman no it does not, it will only do string interpolation, but will return a string. "group_#{x}" will return "group_1", "group_2" but will only return a string. `send("group_#{x}")` on the other hand should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really crappy question (the one on CodeAcademy) because the code blatantly doesn't represent the real world. It's contrived to the point that defining objects around the behavior is challenging. That said, here's another approach that's purely academic — don't ever do this in production code:

```
group_1 = …
group_2 = …
group_3 = …

can_ride_1 = can_ride_2 = can_ride_3 = nil

1.upto(3) do |i|
  group = binding.local_variable_get("group_#{i}")
  binding.local_variable_set("can_ride_#{i}", group.select { |v| v >= 4 })
end
```

Here's another exploitation of this:

```
eligible_riders = -> (group_num) do
  group = binding.local_variable_get("group_#{group_num}")
  group.select { |v| v >= 4 }
end

can_ride_1 = eligible_riders[1]
can_ride_2 = eligible_riders[2]
can_ride_3 = eligible_riders[3]
```

A more appropriate way of doing this would be to extract an object to represent each `group`:

```
class Group < Array
  def select_eligible
    select { |v| v >= 4 }
  end
end

group_1 = Group.new [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
group_2 = Group.new [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
group_3 = Group.new [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

eligible = [group_1, group_2, group_3].map &:select_eligible
can_ride_1, can_ride_2, can_ride_3 = *eligible
```

Or you can take advantage of those splat enhancements using the proc you have:

```
can_ride_1, can_ride_2, can_ride_3 = *[group_1, group_2, group_3].map do |g|
  g.select &over_4_feet
end
```

Comment: Yeah the amount of dancing needed to get to the string interpolation setup is a no go. Still a fun mental exercise in the context (and FWIW, the problem is great at isolating in on different block behaviors as silly as it is on its own). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a variable for each group, you can have an array of groups, so you can `map` it to another array applying your `select` in each element.

```
groups = []

groups.push [4.1, 5.5, 3.2, 3.3, 6.1, 3.9, 4.7]
groups.push [7.0, 3.8, 6.2, 6.1, 4.4, 4.9, 3.0]
groups.push [5.5, 5.1, 3.9, 4.3, 4.9, 3.2, 3.2]

over_4_feet = Proc.new { |height| height >= 4 }

can_ride = groups.map { |group| group.select(&over_4_feet) }

puts can_ride
```

Comment: The variables `group_1`, `group_2`, `group_3` are givens in the question (check the link), so why not skip the creation of another variable and just write `[group_1, group_2, group_3].map ...`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland See the first sentence wherein he states that you don't need to have “a variable for each group”.

Comment: @coreyward, yes, but that changes the question, a no-no. Moreover, the solution should work with any value (array) for each of the three variables. This only works with three literal arrays. Yes, it's a poor question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, the code OP already has is correct (codecademy says it is OK), so I suppose OP does not want a code to pass the codecademy challenge (because he already nailed it). OP just want to know some way to generalize the code because he is seeing a lot of repetition and similar things. The fact this code is from codecademy is irrelevant. Look at the last sentence in the question: "Is it possible, when objects hold repeatable patterns like these do, to use an Enumerable method in this way?"

Comment: Even better is to just declare all the groups in one shot: `groups = [ [ ... ], [ ... ], .... ]` to avoid the repeated `push` calls. Also since that Proc is only used once it might as well be inlined.

Comment: Cool idea though not really why I was going for. Thanks for answering though @Gabriel